# Unable to compile current and previous versions of project

Tags: compilation-error

I am currently working on a project report and suddenly, the report stopped compiling.

Overleaf gives me the following message:

```
Emergency stop.
<*> preamble.tex
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

As far as I'm aware, **I wasn't messing with the pre-amble at the time of occurence**.

Of course I've tried previous versions, but they cannot compile either (I've tried 5 different versions, ranging from 20 minutes old to 3 hours). I KNOW that the project was able to compile at that time, since I was drawing with TikZ (and therefore, compiled like every time I drew a line).

I've also tried a different Overleaf user, different network and computer, clearing the cache, excluding ALL main `tex` files and so on.

Nothing works. Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong? The log is pasted on Codepile: https://www.codepile.net/pile/BD2vyLD5

Comment: You seem to have externalized your preamble in an external file (preamble.tex) and now you are trying to compile this file. Reselect your real main file and compile this.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly the problem. I have NO idea how it happended, since i haven't opened the menu to change the setting. But thank you!

Comment: Well one can select the file to compile by simply clicking on it.

Comment: Just as information for other people who may view this post:

It was actually an error at Overleaf, which caused the main file to be reset. This happended on a number of projects according to the overleaf support team:



"Thanks for getting in touch about this and sorry you're having issues. The key issue is that the main file was reset due to a disturbance in our system, which we apologize for. (The main file can be set up in the project's Menu on top left)."